# GWT - popup position

Tags: gwt

How Do I position a popup in gwt to at mouse position. 
I have a huge flextable and the flextable contains button. If a button is pressed then a popup appears with some data, but the popup always appears at the top of the page.
if a user is at the bottom of the table, then the popup will be out of the view and they are unable to see it?

How to I get the x and y co-ordinates of the mouse position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the Popup, use the `center()` method instead of the `show()` method. This should create a popup and display it in the center of the browser's viewport.

Answer (score 9):

The **showRelativeTo** method of the **PopupPanel** class works well in my use-case.

```
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel.PositionCallback;

public class CommentPanelPopupImage extends Image {
    public CommentPanelPopupImage(final int tableId, final String referenceId, final String title) {
        super("external-link-ltr-icon.png");
        setTitle("Click to see comments");
        final CommentPanelPopupImage commentPanelPopupImage = this;
        addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
                final CommentPopupPanel popup = new CommentPopupPanel(tableId, referenceId, title);
                popup.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PositionCallback() {

                    public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
                        popup.showRelativeTo(commentPanelPopupImage);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get mouse position you can use getClientX/Y() or getScreenX/Y() from the event that has been passed to event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

In you main panel add this and save the coordinates in a global vars object as static (?)

```
main_verticalPanel.addDomHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
                GlobalVars.mouseX = event.getX();
                GlobalVars.mouseY = event.getY();
            }

        }, MouseMoveEvent.getType());
```

Then get the coordinates from elsewhere in your code.